# Appium: Android script getting hanged

Tags: appium

> ```
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_112
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device 110d6e26
> info: [debug] Setting device id to 110d6e26
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: Device API level is: 23
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
> info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
> info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 push "C:\\appium\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
> info: [debug] Enabling Unicode keyboard support
> info: [debug] Pushing unicode ime to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 install "C:\appium\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unicode_ime_apk\UnicodeIME-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "settings get secure default_input_method"
> info: [debug] Unsetting IME 'io.appium.android.ime/.UnicodeIME'
> info: [debug] Setting IME to 'io.appium.android.ime/.UnicodeIME'
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "ime enable io.appium.android.ime/.UnicodeIME"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "ime set io.appium.android.ime/.UnicodeIME"
> info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 install "C:\appium\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 install "C:\appium\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
> info: Starting App
> info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
> info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
> info: [debug] No matching processes found
> info: [debug] Running bootstrap
> info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.amazon.mShop.android -e disableAndroidWatchers false
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
> info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
> info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.amazon.mShop.android/com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity"
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.amazon.mShop.android" and activity "com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity" to be focused
> info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "dumpsys window windows"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
> info: [debug] Device is at release version 6.0.1
> info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
> info: [debug] Setting command timeout to 0 secs
> info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 14614.971 ms - 74 
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3 {}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.amazon.mShop.android","appActivity":"com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity","newCommandTimeout":0,"unicodeKeyboard":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"110d6e26","version":"5.0","deviceName":"110d6e26"},"appPackage":"com.amazon.mShop.android","appActivity":"com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity","newCommandTimeout":0,"unicodeKeyboard":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"110d6e26","version":"5.0","deviceName":"110d6e26"},"sessionId":"d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3"}
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3 200 2.795 ms - 789 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.amazon.mShop.android","appActivity":"com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity","newCommandTimeout":0,"unicodeKeyboard":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"110d6e26","version":"5.0","deviceName":"110d6e26"},"appPackage":"com.amazon.mShop.android","appActivity":"com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity","newCommandTimeout":0,"unicodeKeyboard":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"110d6e26","version":"5.0","deviceName":"110d6e26"},"sessionId":"d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/d3e033dc-9866-443b-880f-72932c478da3/appium/app/reset {}
> info: [debug] Resetting app mid-session
> info: [debug] Running device specific reset
> info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "am force-stop com.amazon.mShop.android"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "pm clear com.amazon.mShop.android"
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.amazon.mShop.android" and activity "com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity" to not be focused
> info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\khajini\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 110d6e26 shell "dumpsys window windows"
> ```

Script are getting hanged here when executing .

Comment: it just hanged here . nor exception and error . tried all the possibilities like upgrading appiue server and all :

Comment: cap.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
cap.setCapability("version", version);
cap.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
cap.setCapability("udid", udid);
cap.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");// this is for
cap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 0);// this is for appium
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.amazon.mShop.android");
cap.setCapability("appActivity",
"com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity");
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
"http://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/wd/hub"), cap);

Comment: its getting hanged at drivercreation and sometime it works fine .